# How to correctly reference an object property in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I'm doing some cleanup after my Xcode 4 migration and noticed a few warnings that I can't get corrected. In the example below I'm trying to build an dynamic url to get an image.

```
NSString* imgUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://images.localhost.com/Image/%@", [selectedHat img]];
```

(selectedHat is an object with a @synth property "img" that is of type NSString)

The warning in Xcode is around how I get the img property from selectedHat

"method img not found (return type defaults to 'id')"

Obviously I'm not after a method (unless objective-c considers the getter on my property to be a method). This approach works fine, but I'm out to cleanup the warnings and understand how I should ask for the img property here going forward

Thank you in advance

**Edit**

The Hat interface looks something like the below

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Hat : NSObject {
  NSString* img;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* img;

@end
```

Comment: The @synthesize directive generates /actual/ methods. object.property invokes a method, as does, object.property = foo (misleading and unclear if you ask me). Also, please post part of the interface of the class in question, so that we might have a look at your declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things. Not sure what your hat class is called, so lets call it `Hat` for this example:

1. Make sure that the `img` property is declared in the *Hat.h*
2. Make sure that you do `#import "Hat.h"` in any file calling this property.

Comment: Just adding the import like you mentioned fixed this warning - thank you!